# Pixelbox shows error image on valid bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, picturebox

I have a wired probly. I recieve pixel data from a web control (Awesomium).
I want to display the bipmap in a PictureBox.

```
using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(viewPortX, viewPortY, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
  {
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
    BitmapSurface bmpSurface = (BitmapSurface)htmlHolder.Surface;
    bmpSurface.CopyTo(bmpData.Scan0, bmpSurface.RowSpan, 4, false, false);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    bmp.Save("result.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    pictureBox.Load(result.jpg);
  }
```

This works fine. The bitmap is diaplayed.
If I change

```
bmp.Save("result.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
pictureBox.Load(result.jpg);
```

to

```
pictureBox.Image = bmp;
```

then the eror image is shown in the PictureBox.
Any idea what's is wrong?
Greetings
Clemens Hoffmann

Comment: You mustn't use the `using`, it will dispose the bitmap then.

Answer (score 1):

because you destroy bmp object before it get's loaded into picturebox. using statement dispose image created within it's range.

Comment: `you destroy bmp object before it get's loaded into picturebox` Is little misleading since `pictureBox.Image = bmp;` loads image. How can you say `before it get's loaded`?

Comment: The `PictureBox.Image` is just a reference to the `Bitmap` which is assigned to it. After the `using`, that `Bitmap` is `Disposed` and the `PictureBox` can't render a `Disposed` bitmap, instead of throwing an explicit exception, the red `X` is rendered.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's misleading. English is not my first language, so please forgive my language errors. I hope that asker understood my answer.